# Use virtual properties to populate objects in lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor

I am struggling to find solid material regarding the use of virtual properties in C#/.NET.

One example where I am trying to simplify many calls to a DB is:

Creating an Order:

Order.cs includes:

```
[Key, Required]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required, ForeignKey(nameof(Patient))]
public int PatientId { get; set; }

[Required, ForeignKey(nameof(Physician))]
public int PhysicianId { get; set; }

public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }

public virtual Physician Physician { get; set; }
```

Patient and Physician contain many properties such as First Name, Last Name, Date-of-birth, etc.

When I create a new order, I am currently trying to hardcode the virtual property 'Patient':

```
var patient = _context.Patients.Where(x => x.Id == o.PatientId).FirstOrDefault();

o.Patient = patient;
```

and for 'Physician' I am using a SelectList ViewBag:

```
var physicians = _context.Physician
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            FullName = $"{x.LastName}, {x.FirstName}",
            LastName = x.LastName,
            FirstName = x.FirstName
        })
        .ToList();

ViewData["PhysicianId"] = new SelectList(physicians.OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ToList(), "Id", "FullName", order.PhysicianId);
```

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Physician)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PhysicianId, ViewData["PhysicianId"] as SelectList, new { @id = "physicians", @class = "form-control w-100" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhysicianId)
</div>
```

The ViewBag method has worked for me before, but isn't now and I don't know why.

How do I use virtual properties (as objects) correctly to populate Order Details, both individually and in a list? Currently 'Patient' and 'Physician' return null.

[image]

View:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.LastName)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Physician.LastName)
</td>
```

Controller:

```
var orders = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync();
return View("Index", orders.OrderByDescending(m => m.OrderDate).ToList());
```

How do I go the other way around... displaying a virtual list of Orders when pulling a Patient or Physician?

Comment: What's the asp.net core version you have used? And could you share your code of Index  action in controller and view?

Comment: 6.0. will add that code now

Comment: How you get the `orders`?

Comment: from db context. fixed above ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, use [.Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager):

```
var orders = await _context.Orders.Include(e => e.Physician).Include(e => e.Patient).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been an issue for me for a long time.